# how to read a specific position in the last line using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a txt file that is too large and has several similar lines, like this:

word1 word2 word3 word4 -553.75

I am interested in the position [4] "the value", that of the last line -553.75

my file text:

```
.
.
word1 word2 word3 word4 -553.20
.
.
.
word1 word2 word3 word4 -553.25
.
.
.
word1 word2 word3 word4 -553.75
.
.
.
```

my script :

```
def main():
    oTE_list = []
    oTE = []

    with open("file.txt","r") as f:
    text = f.readlines()
    for line in text:
        if line[0] == 'word1' and line[1] == 'word2' and line[2] == 'word3' and line[3] == 'word4':
      oTE_list.append(line[4])



    # Change Lists To Number Format
    for idx, item in enumerate(oTE_list):
        if idx == len(oTE_list) - 1:
            print(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but I do not know why it does not work with me!

thank you in advance.

Comment: `line[i]` does not magically refer to the ith word. You'll need to split on space.

Comment: `line = line.srtip().split()` add this after the for statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line is string not list of word, to convert it to list of word use `split` and `strip` before to get rid of `\n`

```
def main():
    oTE_list = []
    oTE = []

    with open("file.txt","r") as f:
    text = f.readlines()
    for line in text:
        line = line.strip().split()
        if line[0] == 'FINAL' and line[1] == 'SINGLE' and line[2] == 'POINT' and line[3] == 'ENERGY':
            oTE_list.append(line[4])



    # Change Lists To Number Format
    for idx, item in enumerate(oTE_list):
        if idx == len(oTE_list) - 1:
            print(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: it does not work. resulted from the execution:

  { File "2.py", line 6
     text = f.readlines ()
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block}

Comment: Please see the indentation, you can solve that yourself. There is some spacing problem somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

way don't you use re and read from the end of the file

```
import re
with open("file1.txt","r") as f:
    for line in reversed(f.readlines()):
        if re.search('word1.*word2.*word3.*word4',line):
            print(line.split(' ')[-1])
            break
```

Comment: print line.split(' ')[-1] :  SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Sorry I missed that you're using Python3 replaced to print line for python3 print

Comment: Happy to help, If this solved you'r problem you can simply mark the solution as helpful (By clicking the little arrow up icon) and others may benefit from your question

Comment: thank you for the effort and the time you spent,    thank you "Ron", again once I failed.
there is not an error message, but it does print nothing !,
@my goal is to print: **-553.75**@

Comment: Can you give a more accurate representation of your input file? Have you replaced word1,word2.... What the actual strings?