# how to change the execution (execution = read and print) of python script: python script.py file.txt to python script.py

Tags: python

I managed to write a script (script2.py), which gives a good result, (output = -553.75).
[**the answer to the question:** [how to read a specific position in the last line using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47293645/how-to-read-a-specific-position-in-the-last-line-using-python#])

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, os
import datetime
import time as t
# Define Variables 
omega = 0
numBasisLst = []
numBasis = []
oTE_list = []
oTE = []





# Open File
fileName = sys.argv[1]
outputFile = open(fileName, 'r')

# Sort Input Into Lists
for line in outputFile:
  line = line.split() # split lines into lists
  if not line: # skip empty lines
    continue
  if len(line) >= 3:
    if line[0] == 'word1' and line[1] == 'word2' and line[2] == 'word3' and line[3] == 'word4':
      oTE_list.append(line[4])




# Change Lists To Number Format
for item in oTE_list:
  oTE.append(float(item))



for idx, item in enumerate(oTE):      
    if idx == len(oTE) - 1:
        print(item)
```

but executing as follows: **python script2.py file.txt**.

my question is ; how to change the script2.py in order to execute as follows: $ **python script2.py**

[image]

Comment: That's a shell/permission thing - execute `chmod +x ./script2.py` to give `script2.py` execution permission.

Comment: hi metatoaster, in this case, my script can not know file.txt
outputFile = open (fileName, 'r')

Comment: just define `fileName = 'file.txt'`?

Comment: it does not work, I did not understand.

Comment: ooooH, ok. I just need to change:                                                    
#fileName = sys.argv [1]
outputFile = open ('file.txt', 'r')
thank you metatoaster

Comment: Or you could have literally typed out the same line I wrote under your original `fileName = sys.argv[1]` line...